# Spring MVC java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, sessionfactory

**The below given code is throwing nullpointerexception, when the session object is trying to get the current session.
Even I have used the @autowired and @repository annotation.
Along with it the Entities are prroperly mentioned
please check and help. 
I am using Postgres Database and Hibernate 3**

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>G-Set-Score</display-name>

<servlet>  
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  



</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Specifying base package of the Components like Controller, Service,
    DAO -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gSetScore.secure" />


<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- View Resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- DataSource -->
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver">
</property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Recruitment"></property>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"></property>
    <property name="password" value="password"></property>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">recruitmentSchema</prop>
            <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.gSetScore.secure.entity">
</property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

JobseekerDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class JobseekerDaoImpl implements JobseekerDao {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Boolean isJobseekerExists(JobseekerAccount jobseekerAccount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session sessionLocal=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction=sessionLocal.getTransaction();
        try {
            transaction.begin();
            String sql="FROM :TABLE WHERE EMAIL = :EMAIL";
            Query query=sessionLocal.createQuery(sql);
            query.setParameter(":TABLE", "Jobseeker_Account");
            query.setParameter(":EMAIL", jobseekerAccount.getJobseekerEmail());
            List<JobseekerAccount> list=query.list();
            transaction.commit();
            if(list.isEmpty()==false) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sessionLocal.close();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gSetScore.secure.DaoImpl.JobseekerDaoImpl.isJobseekerExists(JobseekerDaoImpl.java:28)
    at com.gSetScore.secure.ServiceImpl.JobseekerServiceImpl.validateJobseekerLoginDetailsFromDatabase(JobseekerServiceImpl.java:28)
    at com.gSetScore.secure.controller.JobseekerController.verifyJobseekerLoginDetails(JobseekerController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1374)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you please check your startup logs. Seems your app can't connect to DB.

Comment: when the error is NP it's really useful if you could point where is the null variable that is causing the problem

Comment: Please, add the code where you call `JobseekerDaoImpl`.